# Prolog - How does this permute function work?

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

For the life of me I can't figure out how *exactly* this permute function works.

```
perm(L, [H|T]) :-
    append(V, [H|U], L),
    append(V,U,W),
    perm(W,T).
perm([],[]).
```

It looks to me like the first append takes the last element of L and unifies it with H. Then the inner perm call permutes the other elements and unifies them with T. I'm just not sure what the second append function does.  I know that without it, every attempt to find a new solution reduces the list size by 1, but I can't explain this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried using trace? (Run: trace, perm([1,2,3],X) for ex)

Comment: Try to think about it *relationally* not *functionally*... *`[H|T]` is a permutation of `L` if `L` is `[H|U]` appended to `V` and...*. And *`[]` is a permutation of `[]`*.

Comment: Yes, many times.  It's still confusing to me.  Say I input perm([1,2,3],X).  The last 3 traces will show me:

   Exit: (8) perm([1], [1]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) perm([1, 2], [2, 1]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) perm([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]) ? creep

which looks like it magically created the permutation to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks to me like the first append takes the last element of `L` and unifies it with `H`.

Not the last element; *some* element.

`append(V, [H|U], L)` can be read `L = V + [H] + U`, for some lists `V` and `U`, and some element `H`. It breaks `L` into a part before `H` and a part after `H`, after picking an element `H`:

```
?- append(V, [H|U], [1,2,3]).
V = [],
H = 1,
U = [2, 3] ;
V = [1],
H = 2,
U = [3] ;
V = [1, 2],
H = 3,
U = [] ;
false.
```

The next `append` can then be read `W = V + U`, so `W` is `L` but with some element `H` removed.

(SWI-Prolog has a `select` predicate that does the same thing in a more readable way:

```
perm(L, [H|T]) :-
    select(H, L, Rest),
    perm(Rest, T).
perm([], []).
```

But it also has a `permutation` predicate, so why bother ;)

Comment: Moreover, SWI's permutation/2 predicate also terminates when *either* argument is sufficiently instantiated. Example: `?- permutation(Ls, [a,b,c]).` The version above does not terminate in this case.

Comment: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/e36d3fd7c56615b83e5c7ae9ba249fbd850f27d1/library/lists.pl. why it can  terminates ? the tech is not trival.